# SwipeRefreshLayout need to freeze UI

Tags: android, progressdialog, swiperefreshlayout

I started converting the old `ProgressDialog` in my `Asynctask` to `SwipeRefreshLayout` .
the `ProgressDialog` insured that the UI freezes till the `Asynctask` is fully done .

how to freeze the UI when using `SwipeRefreshLayout` if there is any need to freeze it ?

Comment: Not getting the problem exactly what you want make it clear than only can help.

Comment: please check my edited question

Comment: ok so please post your asynctask too so make question completely understandable and to find where you doing wrong and don't think so you need to use async for swipe to refresh

Comment: @AjayPandya I think what she wants is that, just as when the progress dialog is in view, so the screen is dimmed and the views behind the progress dialog cannot be clicked. In other words dialog is not cancel able.

Comment: not a problem in the code , but if i try to trigger any AsyncTask from swipeRefresh , the UI must  freeze , i have no idea how to implement this idea

Comment: yes i got your point @EricB.

Comment: @SarahMaher UI Freezes means stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implement SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener there is one overriden method onRefresh() in which you can manage your other views like make clickable all the buttons or make them unclickable.

You can also put one transparent layer for manage whole screen clickable and unclickable easily.

You can add one parent layout like frame in your xml which background will goes to transparent.

Now what you have to do is when you want to disable click of your screen set that transparent layout visibility as visible and don't attach click listener for that layout so automatically sub view's will unclickable,and make that view gone when you want to allow user to click the views this is it. hope you get concept

Comment: can i have a code snippet/example for the transparent layer ?

Comment: @SarahMaher check my updated answer that will provide some hint for implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a work around. When you pull to refresh show a dialog, and change the visibility of the views to invisible, so you will get the screen dimmed, and you can close the dialog once the refresh is done.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. But may be someone will get benefit from my answer someday. So here we go!

Use the following code **when refresh start**, to freeze the UI.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Following code **after refresh**, to get touch events back

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a layout on your view with transparent or semitransparent background. Make sure that this background cover all of your view. But remind that you should set android:clickable="true" for your layout. Then the items under this transparent layout can not be clicked and so you made your layout freezing and no item could be selected anymore. for example you can use some layout like this:

```html
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@android/color:transparent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
```